# Hatcher exercise $\bf 2.2.30\left(e\right)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Compute the homology of the mapping torus $T_f$ of the map $f:S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ that interchanges the two factors and then reflects one of the factors.

From the l.e.s of the mapping torus,
$$0\to H_3(T_f)\to H_2(S^1\times S^1)\xrightarrow{1-f_*} H_2(S^1\times S^1)\to H_2(T_f).$$
First, the image of the standard CW structure of the torus under $f$ is just a rotation which is orietation preserving homeomorphism so $f_* = 1$. But if I consider $H_2(S^1\times S^1)\simeq H_1(S^1)\otimes H_1(S^1)\simeq\Bbb Z$, then $f_*(a\otimes b) = -b\otimes a$ so $f_*(1) = -1$. So they are different. What is the correct one?

Comment: Remember the product is graded commutative, so $a\otimes b = -b\otimes a$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito That's for cohomology ring isn't it?

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Sorry.

Comment: Besides just the raw permutation of the cells of the CW complex, you must also take into account their orientations; and, of course, even in order for the orientations to be defined you must first choose a characteristic map to parameterize each cell.

Comment: @LeeMosher So the interpretation using tensor is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is that the map $H_k(X) \otimes H_l(Y) \to H_{k + l}(X \times Y)$ is only natural with respect to maps of the form $f(x,y) = (g(x), h(y))$. And the map on $X \times X$ switching the two factors induces the map $a \otimes b$ to $(-1)^{\deg a \deg b} b \otimes a$ on $H_*(X \times X) \cong H_*(X)^{\otimes 2}$ (and this is why the cup product is graded commutative). If you use that your $f$ is a composition of one map that acts factorwise and the factor-switching map then combining these two facts you indeed get that $f_* = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand. $H_2(S^1\times S^1)\simeq H_1(S^1)\otimes H_1(S^1)$ is from Kunneth formula. Also the cup product is for cohomology not for homology.

Comment: I agree that the Kunneth formula gives you that isomorphism, but how do you get $f_*(a \otimes b) = -b \otimes a$ from there?

Comment: Since $f$ interchanges two factors and reflects one of the factors, if $a,b$ are generators (or just elements) of $H_1(S^1\times\{*\})$ and $H_1(\{*\}\times S^1)$, then $f_*(a\otimes b) = -b\otimes a$.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the map on $H_2(S^1 \times S^1)$ is taken, under this isomorphism, to the map on $H_1(S^1) \otimes H_1(S^1)$ given by including each factor as the product with the basepoint, applying $f$ and then projecting. There is a relation of that form, but this "cross product" on homology is also graded commutative, and this is essentially why the cup product is graded commutative.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!